# How to remove index.php from Codeigniter (nginx)

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I'm trying to remove the `index.php?` using Codeigniter whith nginx server, but it doesn´t work. I tryed the official solution of nginx website https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/
Actually, in the default file, i have the following code:

```
server {
        listen 99 default_server;
        listen [::]:99 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        autoindex on;
        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;



        index index.php;
location / {
    set $page_to_view "/index.php";
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    root   /var/www/site;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/site$page_to_view;
}

# rewrites
location @rewrites {
    if ($uri ~* ^/([a-z]+)$) {
        set $page_to_view "/$1.php";
        rewrite ^/([a-z]+)$ /$1.php last;
    }
}

}
```

And the config.php file is the following:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

The result of any request is 502 Bad Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /var/www/html/ci;
    autoindex on;
    index index.php;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location = /index.php {

            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:6969;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/ci$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 444;
    }
```

}

and config file

```
  $config['base_url'] = "";
  $config['index_page']       = "";
  $config['uri_protocol']     = "AUTO";
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, but i try to implement this solution before and it doesn´t work. Maybe i must clarify that i implement the nginx official solution